# Android data folder empty in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Somes times i can access the data folder in eclipse some times not.
Most of the time the data folder is off limits.

I'm suspecting that is has to do with the way i connect my phone to my pc.
When debugging i have to use the internet pass through option.
Funny enough this does not give the phone internet access, but does allow for some debugging.
(If it does not require internet access that is)
When testing my app's internet features i have to shut down internet pass through.
And connect via. wireless.
Now. when going back to "internet pass through" i don't have any access to the data folder.
I have to restart my pc.
I'm simply dumbfounded how stupendously FUB infinity android development is sometimes.
Has anybody developed any useful working processes around android debugging, file accessing while connected to the internet?
Any useful tools for file access would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only see the data folder on your phone if its rooted

Comment: I wonder how i got access to the files earlier today.
Btw. is rooting supposed to take half an hour or so?

Comment: Still not rootet. But i have got access to the android files again, after a reboot. Very strange.